# GITLAB-API-PYTHON- how import package from gitlab - file.py?

Tags: python, api, import, gitlab, package

My code is work but... i think about simple solution.
Maybe someone knows?

I can't find in API Gitlab how import package from GitLab - file .py

In database_connect.py i have function with connect to database (example)

For example

```
database_connect = project.files.get(file_path='FUNCTION/DATABASE/database_connect.py', ref='main')
import database_connect
```

My code ...

```
import gitlab 
import base64

gl = gitlab.Gitlab('link', 
                   private_token='API')
projects = gl.projects.list()
for project in projects[3:4]:
    # print(project) # prints all the meta data for the project
    print("Project: ", project.name)
    print("Gitlab URL: ", project.http_url_to_repo)
    database_connect = project.files.get(file_path='FUNCTION/DATABASE/database_connect.py', ref='main')
    database_connect_content = base64.b64decode(database_connect.content).decode("utf-8")
    database_connect_package = database_connect_content.replace('\\n', '\n')
    exec(database_connect_package)
```

Comment: if i understand correctly you want to get a particular file from a gitlab repo

Comment: My read is the OP wants to import the contents of a file pulled directly from the GitLab API. Generally I’d say don’t do this. And there certainly isn’t a simple out of the box way. You have a working solution, but this is not a good practice. Clone the repo and run locally, or version, package, and install the module using standard python deployment techniques like pip.

Comment: Origin - i want use function from file in gitlab repo :)  I thought the API supports function imports like this.
Micheal Delgado - You're right that it's a weak solution even though it works. I try your advice. It seemed to me - as I wrote above - that it is possible to elegantly import from gitlab by specifying the path to the file of a given function